# Swift use generic function in generic class

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I'm developing an app using Generic.

But there is a problem using generic function in generic class.

As you know, we use generic like :

```
class ClassA{
    static func myFunction<Type>()->Type where Type : Protocol1, Type : Protocol2{
        ...
        return Type
    }
}


class ClassB{
    func myFunction(){
        let a : ClassC = ClassA.myFunction()
    }
}

class ClassC : Protocol1, Protocol2{

}
```

And, this works well.

But what I want to do is :

```
class ClassA{
    static func myFunction<Type>()->Type where Type : Protocol1, Type : Protocol2{
        ...
        return Type
    }
}


class ClassB<Type : Protocol1, Protocol2>{
    func myFunction(){
        let a : Type = ClassA.myFunction()
    }
}
```

And this code gives me "Generic parameter 'Type' could not be inferred" error.

I tried with :

```
class ClassB<Type> where Type : Protocol1, Type : Protocol2{
```

But it was no use...

Is it possible to use generic type to infer other generic type?

Comment: The problem is merely that you said `ClassB<Type : Protocol1, Protocol2>` – which defines *two* generic placeholders, `Type` and `Protocol2`. You wanted to say `ClassB<Type : Protocol1 & Protocol2>`, which defines a *single* generic placeholder `Type`, which conforms to both `Protocol1` and `Protocol2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you messed up with a type inference a bit. How does it work: usually you have something like this:

```
var a = "Some string"
```

In this case type of `a` inferred thanks to assigned value - it is known that it is `String` and nothing else.

More complicated example:

```
func returnString() -> String {
    return "Some string"
}
var b = returnString()
```

In this case type inferred from function signature, from return type - it is `String` and it is stated in its signature: `-> String`. Compiler knows for sure, `b` will be of type `String`.

With generics type inference becomes a bit more complicated. Let's look at your function:

```
let a : Type = ClassA.myFunction()
```

What do we see here? `a` is of unknown type, compiler should infer type from function you're calling. Let's do this! Look at the function signature:

```
static func myFunction<Type>()->Type where Type : Protocol1, Type : Protocol2
```

As a compiler I would be confused, since return type of function must be in turn inferred from somewhere else, and in this case "somewhere" is exactly the type of variable you defined and wanted assign to (because there is nowhere else, really). But, you didn't specify type of variable either. This is exactly why you're getting "Generic parameter 'Type' could not be inferred" error - **both sides of expression have unknown type and must be inferred from each other**.

It works here:

```
let a : ClassC = ClassA.myFunction()
```

exactly because of that - you specified not abstract type, but concrete type `: ClassC` and compiler knows, that it must substitute `Type` in `func myFunction ...` with `ClassC`.

To conclude, I would say that with generic functions like yours type inference works in entirely different direction - instead of inferring type of variable from function being called, type of function inferred from variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I thought compiler could infer type more later. Like (Class -> Generic Class -> Static Generic Function), but I guess it can't. I really appericiate your help!

Comment: What do you mean "*`a` is of unknown type*"? The compiler knows that it must be of type `Type`, because that's what it's annotated as.

Comment: @Hamish it may be not the best choice of words, but I hope idea is clear - neither compiler, nor you could really say what `Type` really is. It isn't implemented somewhere and, in fact, it's just a placeholder for some concrete type.

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok Sure, it's a placeholder for a type, but so is the generic placeholder in the `myFunction` function – which can be satisfied by the `ClassB`'s generic placeholder. The *actual* problem here is that OP incorrectly defined `ClassB`'s generic placeholder – [see my above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800521/swift-use-generic-function-in-generic-class#comment70798098_41800521).

Comment: @Hamish, well, yes, I entirely missed the point of question, seems you're right. Write your comment as answer and let's wait for OP